# Are there any Esperanto resources about shogi ("Japanese chess")?

Tags: resources

I plan to learn [Shogi](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Cogio), a Japanese game similar to chess. So I was wondering if there are any Esperanto resources for learning shogi that go beyond a brief overview of the piece movements, promotions, etc. The external link at the bottom of the [Wikipedia article](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Cogio#Eksteraj_ligiloj) is not sufficient. Ideally, I would like a resource that also basic tactics.

I would normally ask this type of question on Board & Cardgames Stack Exchange, but that site appears to have [very few questions about shogi](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shogi), let alone people who are aware of resources in Esperanto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know any good free resources, but I have read there are some good book on Shogi in Esperanto by Ueda Tomohiko.

You can buy his guide for beginners [[over here]](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=5137) on the UEA catalog, and [[here]](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=6418) is his book with exercises for more advanced players who finished the first book.

About the first book someone wrote:

> La lernolibro ”Invito al Japana Ŝako”, eldonita de Esperantista Klubo de Japana Ŝako, estas tre bonvena, kaj espereble malfermos al multaj interesitoj la mirindan mondon de ĉi tiu variaĵo de ŝako. La libro enhavas ne nur la bazajn regulojn de la ludo, sed ankaŭ ampleksajn klarigojn pri strategio kaj dekpaĝan terminaron japanan-esperantan-anglan.

So that sounds like exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: According to Chuck Smith some people recommend Invito al Japana Sxako as an introductory text above either Japanese or English books because of its broad approach. Here's where I found his comments: http://blogs.transparent.com/esperanto/is-your-hobby-a-waste-of-time/